# Microstates and Schrodinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

[Pathria, statistical mechanics](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Statistical_Mechanics/PIk9sF9j2oUC?hl=en), pg2 ,when discussing $N$ particles in a volume $V$

> ...there will be a large number of different
> ways in which the total energy E of the system can be distributed among the N particles
> constituting it. Each of these (different) ways specifies a microstate, or complexion, of the
> given system.

> Each of these (different) ways specifies a microstate, or complexion, of the
> given system. In general, the various microstates, or complexions, of a given system can
> be identified with the independent solutions $ψ(r_1,..., r_N )$ of the Schrodinger equation of
> the system, corresponding to the eigenvalue E of the relevant Hamiltonian

If we have N particles in a box, we solve the energy eigenvalue for the total system  $H|E>=E|E>$ and find the eigenvectors.

Using linear combination of these and boundary conditions  we find the general solution $ψ(r_1,..., r_N )$.

So how does "the various microstates, or complexions, of a given system can
be identified with the independent solutions $ψ(r1,..., rN )$ of the Schrodinger equation of
the system, corresponding to the eigenvalue E of the relevant Hamiltonian" enter the discussion?

Comment: If you find that there are $M$ linearly independent solutions to the Schrodinger equation with energy $E$, then you can say that the microstates of the system are those $M$ solutions. Does that make sense?

Comment: Suppose one of the eigenstate of Hamiltonian with eigenvalue E is | v>. This is a solution to the energy eigenvalue equation, but how does that imply it correspondens to one microstate?

Comment: A microstate is a possible configuration of the microscopic degrees of freedom. $|\nu\rangle$, as a solution of the Schrodinger equation, is a possible configuration of the microscopic degrees of freedom.